# apt-get tries to configure a removed kernel while installing a module

Tags: apt, kernel

When I'm trying to apt-get update/upgrade or anything related to the kernel I get the following trace.

The kernel 3.5.0 is a kernel that was  manually installed and manually removed. I probably missed something in the removal, and apt-get thinks it still exist.
 
Overall the commands fails, packages I want to remove still exist.

```
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-31-generic-pae
INFO:Enable nvidia-current
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/nvidia-common/quirks/put_your_quirks_here
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/nvidia-common/quirks/dell_latitude
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/nvidia-common/quirks/lenovo_thinkpad
DEBUG:Processing quirk Latitude E6530
DEBUG:Failure to match Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd. with Dell Inc.
DEBUG:Quirk doesn't match
DEBUG:Processing quirk ThinkPad T420s
DEBUG:Failure to match Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd. with LENOVO
DEBUG:Quirk doesn't match
Removing old nvidia-current-295.40 DKMS files...
Loading new nvidia-current-295.40 DKMS files...
Error! DKMS tree already contains: nvidia-current-295.40
You cannot add the same module/version combo more than once.
dpkg: error processing nvidia-current (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 3
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Processing triggers for bamfdaemon ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf.index...
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.5.0
grep: /boot/config-3.5.0: No such file or directory
WARNING: missing /lib/modules/3.5.0
Device driver support needs thus be built-in linux image!
WARNING: Couldn't open directory /lib/modules/3.5.0: No such file or directory
FATAL: Could not open /lib/modules/3.5.0/modules.dep.temp for writing: No such file or directory
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/3.5.0/modules.dep: No such file or directory
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/3.5.0/modules.dep: No such file or directory
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/3.5.0/modules.dep: No such file or directory
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/3.5.0/modules.dep: No such file or directory
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/3.5.0/modules.dep: No such file or directory
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/3.5.0/modules.dep: No such file or directory
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/3.5.0/modules.dep: No such file or directory
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/3.5.0/modules.dep: No such file or directory
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/3.5.0/modules.dep: No such file or directory
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/3.5.0/modules.dep: No such file or directory
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/3.5.0/modules.dep: No such file or directory
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/3.5.0/modules.dep: No such file or directory
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/3.5.0/modules.dep: No such file or directory
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/3.5.0/modules.dep: No such file or directory
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/3.5.0/modules.dep: No such file or directory
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/3.5.0/modules.dep: No such file or directory
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/3.5.0/modules.dep: No such file or directory
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/3.5.0/modules.dep: No such file or directory
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/3.5.0/modules.dep: No such file or directory
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/3.5.0/modules.dep: No such file or directory
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/3.5.0/modules.dep: No such file or directory
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/3.5.0/modules.dep: No such file or directory
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/3.5.0/modules.dep: No such file or directory
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/3.5.0/modules.dep: No such file or directory
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/3.5.0/modules.dep: No such file or directory
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/3.5.0/modules.dep: No such file or directory
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/3.5.0/modules.dep: No such file or directory
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/3.5.0/modules.dep: No such file or directory
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/3.5.0/modules.dep: No such file or directory
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/3.5.0/modules.dep: No such file or directory
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/3.5.0/modules.dep: No such file or directory
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/3.5.0/modules.dep: No such file or directory
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/3.5.0/modules.dep: No such file or directory
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/3.5.0/modules.dep: No such file or directory
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/3.5.0/modules.dep: No such file or directory
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/3.5.0/modules.dep: No such file or directory
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/3.5.0/modules.dep: No such file or directory
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/3.5.0/modules.dep: No such file or directory
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/3.5.0/modules.dep: No such file or directory
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/3.5.0/modules.dep: No such file or directory
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/3.5.0/modules.dep: No such file or directory
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/3.5.0/modules.dep: No such file or directory
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/3.5.0/modules.dep: No such file or directory
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/3.5.0/modules.dep: No such file or directory
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/3.5.0/modules.dep: No such file or directory
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/3.5.0/modules.dep: No such file or directory
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/3.5.0/modules.dep: No such file or directory
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/3.5.0/modules.dep: No such file or directory
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/3.5.0/modules.dep: No such file or directory
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/3.5.0/modules.dep: No such file or directory
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/3.5.0/modules.dep: No such file or directory
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/3.5.0/modules.dep: No such file or directory
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/3.5.0/modules.dep: No such file or directory
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/3.5.0/modules.dep: No such file or directory
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/3.5.0/modules.dep: No such file or directory
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/3.5.0/modules.dep: No such file or directory
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/3.5.0/modules.dep: No such file or directory
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/3.5.0/modules.dep: No such file or directory
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/3.5.0/modules.dep: No such file or directory
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/3.5.0/modules.dep: No such file or directory
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/3.5.0/modules.dep: No such file or directory
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/3.5.0/modules.dep: No such file or directory
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/3.5.0/modules.dep: No such file or directory
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/3.5.0/modules.dep: No such file or directory
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/3.5.0/modules.dep: No such file or directory
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/3.5.0/modules.dep: No such file or directory
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/3.5.0/modules.dep: No such file or directory
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/3.5.0/modules.dep: No such file or directory
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/3.5.0/modules.dep: No such file or directory
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/3.5.0/modules.dep: No such file or directory
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/3.5.0/modules.dep: No such file or directory
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/3.5.0/modules.dep: No such file or directory
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/3.5.0/modules.dep: No such file or directory
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/3.5.0/modules.dep: No such file or directory
Errors were encountered while processing:
 nvidia-current
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Have you seen that? http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1542698

Comment: By manually what do you mean? Did you compile it yourself or install a .deb from somewhere, or something else?

Answer (score 4):

Check the following locations for remnants of the old kernel:

- /usr/src/
- /lib/modules/
- /var/lib/initramfs-tools/

Comment: I don't know if I should wake up this old thread, but I'm in the same situation. How exactly do you update the locations for the kernel?

Comment: @nitnelave look in each of those directories. If there are any folders that match the problem kernel's version (**exactly**), then delete them with sudo.